# Windows - Create User Folder with specific NTFS rights using CMD

Tags: windows-7, windows, ntfs, cmd.exe

Situation:

I'm currently making a default Windows image for our new PCs. 
These new systems come with an SSD (250GB) + HDD (500GB). 
My goal is to have the main user profile still on the SSD, but redirect some of the user folder (Documents, Desktop, Movies, Music, Downloads) to the HDD.
So in the end the SSD is only used for settings and stuff like that and the HDD for most of the users' files.

My Method:

Create Local GPO with logon script for all non administrators:

> check if user folder (%USERNAME%) exists in d:\Users\ if not create the necessary folder
>   structure and deleted the now unnecessary folders in c:\Users\%username%
>   (no duplicates)

And of course the registry changes for the folder redirection.

(We don't have a domain, so I have to configure this through local GPOs only)

This seems to work great. The only problem is that if there are more than one users using the system they can access the other users data folder on the HDD without problems.

Is it possible to create a folder in a batch script with specific NTFS rights so only the owner/creator (non admin) and administrators can access it. Other normal users will be blocked.

Comment: You can use [icacls](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) in a batch file to modify permissions.

Comment: See also [so] question [How to grant permission to users for a directory using command line in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2928738)

Comment: is it possible to run this as the normal user or would i need to do a work arround using the system user?

Comment: You probably have to be an `Admin` user if the files are not owned by you.

Answer (score 1):

An owner of a file/folder can always change the security (even if security forbids it). And likewise an admin can always take ownership of an object (even if security forbids it).

If an admin creates something then it is owned by the administrator's group not the individual.

Security is normally inhierited from the parent folder.

There is a security virtual user called Owner/Creator - which refers to whichever user is the owner.

So you need to set up the parent folder correctly, then everything else should be automatic.

Remember the folder get created automatically, either at first logon and always at first use.

**Moreon special folders**

Click Start - All Programs - Accessories - Run (or press Winkey + R). Type

```
sendto
```

One can use the `shell:` protocol to open and create special folders.

To open Documents and create if it doesn't exist

Click Start - All Programs - Accessories - Run (or press Winkey + R). Type

```
shell:personal
```

To get a list of folders that can be used with the shell: protocol

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste).

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\FolderDescriptions" /v Name /s |findstr /c:Name|sort /+23
```

Which on Vista returns

```
Name    REG_SZ    AddNewProgramsFolder
Name    REG_SZ    Administrative Tools
Name    REG_SZ    AppData
Name    REG_SZ    AppUpdatesFolder
Name    REG_SZ    Cache
Name    REG_SZ    CD Burning
Name    REG_SZ    ChangeRemoveProgramsFolder
Name    REG_SZ    Common Administrative Tools
Name    REG_SZ    Common AppData
Name    REG_SZ    Common Desktop
Name    REG_SZ    Common Documents
Name    REG_SZ    Common Programs
Name    REG_SZ    Common Start Menu
Name    REG_SZ    Common Startup
Name    REG_SZ    Common Templates
Name    REG_SZ    CommonDownloads
Name    REG_SZ    CommonMusic
Name    REG_SZ    CommonPictures
Name    REG_SZ    CommonVideo
Name    REG_SZ    ConflictFolder
Name    REG_SZ    ConnectionsFolder
Name    REG_SZ    Contacts
Name    REG_SZ    ControlPanelFolder
Name    REG_SZ    Cookies
Name    REG_SZ    CredentialManager
Name    REG_SZ    CryptoKeys
Name    REG_SZ    CSCFolder
Name    REG_SZ    Default Gadgets
Name    REG_SZ    Desktop
Name    REG_SZ    Downloads
Name    REG_SZ    DpapiKeys
Name    REG_SZ    Favorites
Name    REG_SZ    Fonts
Name    REG_SZ    Gadgets
Name    REG_SZ    Games
Name    REG_SZ    GameTasks
Name    REG_SZ    History
Name    REG_SZ    InternetFolder
Name    REG_SZ    Links
Name    REG_SZ    Local AppData
Name    REG_SZ    LocalAppDataLow
Name    REG_SZ    LocalizedResourcesDir
Name    REG_SZ    MAPIFolder
Name    REG_SZ    My Music
Name    REG_SZ    My Pictures
Name    REG_SZ    My Video
Name    REG_SZ    MyComputerFolder
Name    REG_SZ    NetHood
Name    REG_SZ    NetworkPlacesFolder
Name    REG_SZ    OEM Links
Name    REG_SZ    Original Images
Name    REG_SZ    Personal
Name    REG_SZ    PhotoAlbums
Name    REG_SZ    Playlists
Name    REG_SZ    PrintersFolder
Name    REG_SZ    PrintHood
Name    REG_SZ    Profile
Name    REG_SZ    ProgramFiles
Name    REG_SZ    ProgramFilesCommon
Name    REG_SZ    ProgramFilesCommonX86
Name    REG_SZ    ProgramFilesX86
Name    REG_SZ    Programs
Name    REG_SZ    Public
Name    REG_SZ    PublicGameTasks
Name    REG_SZ    Quick Launch
Name    REG_SZ    Recent
Name    REG_SZ    RecycleBinFolder
Name    REG_SZ    ResourceDir
Name    REG_SZ    SampleMusic
Name    REG_SZ    SamplePictures
Name    REG_SZ    SamplePlaylists
Name    REG_SZ    SampleVideos
Name    REG_SZ    SavedGames
Name    REG_SZ    Searches
Name    REG_SZ    SearchHomeFolder
Name    REG_SZ    SendTo
Name    REG_SZ    Start Menu
Name    REG_SZ    Startup
Name    REG_SZ    SyncCenterFolder
Name    REG_SZ    SyncResultsFolder
Name    REG_SZ    SyncSetupFolder
Name    REG_SZ    System
Name    REG_SZ    SystemCertificates
Name    REG_SZ    SystemX86
Name    REG_SZ    Templates
Name    REG_SZ    TreePropertiesFolder
Name    REG_SZ    UserProfiles
Name    REG_SZ    UsersFilesFolder
Name    REG_SZ    Windows
```

Here's another way. The point of this post is the folders have brief descriptions.

According to the programming documentation executing a paticular command to open a special folder will create that folder if it doesn't exist.

If vDir is set to one of the ShellSpecialFolderConstants and the special folder does not exist, this function will create the folder.

Create the following two lines in notepad. Replace 0 after open with the number from the below list of the folder you want to open and create if it doesn't exist. Folders such as Documents and Videos have two folders, a personal one and one common to all users.

```
set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.Open(0)
```

Here's an example for the two video folders.

This little program attempts to open your personal video folder and the common video folder.

Copy the below three lines into notepad. Save it as "OpenAndCreateVideoFolders.vbs" (the quotes are part of what you need to type for name and will disappear once saved)

```
set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.Open(13)
objShell.Open(55)
```

Double click the little program you just wrote.

**List of Special Folders**

```
CSIDL_DESKTOP 0 Desktop 
CSIDL_INTERNET 1 Internet Explorer (icon on desktop) 
CSIDL_PROGRAMS 2 Start Menu\Programs 
CSIDL_CONTROLS 3 My Computer\Control Panel 
CSIDL_PRINTERS 4 My Computer\Printers 
CSIDL_PERSONAL 5 My Documents 
CSIDL_FAVORITES 6 \Favorites 
CSIDL_STARTUP 7 Start Menu\Programs\Startup 
CSIDL_RECENT 8 \Recent 
CSIDL_SENDTO 9 \SendTo 
CSIDL_BITBUCKET 10 \Recycle Bin 
CSIDL_STARTMENU 11 \Start Menu 
CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS 5 Personal was just a silly name for My Documents 
CSIDL_MYMUSIC 12 "My Music" folder 
CSIDL_MYVIDEO 13 "My Videos" folder 
CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY 16 \Desktop 
CSIDL_DRIVES 17 My Computer 
CSIDL_NETWORK 18 Network Neighborhood (My Network Places) 
CSIDL_NETHOOD 19 \nethood 
CSIDL_FONTS 20 windows\fonts 
CSIDL_TEMPLATES 21 
CSIDL_COMMON_STARTMENU 22 All Users\Start Menu 
CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS 23 All Users\Start Menu\Programs 
CSIDL_COMMON_STARTUP 24 All Users\Startup 
CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY 25 All Users\Desktop 
CSIDL_APPDATA 26 \Application Data 
CSIDL_PRINTHOOD 27 \PrintHood 
CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA 28 \Local Settings\Applicaiton Data (non roaming) 
CSIDL_ALTSTARTUP 29 non localized startup 
CSIDL_COMMON_ALTSTARTUP 30 non localized common startup 
CSIDL_COMMON_FAVORITES 31 Never actually implemented 
CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE 32 Temp Internet Files 
CSIDL_COOKIES 33 Internet cookies 
CSIDL_HISTORY 34 Internet History 
CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA 35 All Users\Application Data 
CSIDL_WINDOWS 36 GetWindowsDirectory() 
CSIDL_SYSTEM 37 GetSystemDirectory() 
CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES 38 C:\Program Files 
CSIDL_MYPICTURES 39 C:\Program Files\My Pictures 
CSIDL_PROFILE 40 USERPROFILE 
CSIDL_SYSTEMX86 41 x86 system directory on RISC 
CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 42 x86 C:\Program Files on RISC 
CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES_COMMON 43 C:\Program Files\Common 
CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES_COMMONX86 44 x86 Program Files\Common on RISC 
CSIDL_COMMON_TEMPLATES 45 All Users\Templates 
CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS 46 All Users\Documents 
CSIDL_COMMON_ADMINTOOLS 47 All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools 
CSIDL_ADMINTOOLS 48 \Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools 
CSIDL_CONNECTIONS 49 Network and Dial-up Connections 
CSIDL_COMMON_MUSIC 53 All Users\My Music 
CSIDL_COMMON_PICTURES 54 All Users\My Pictures 
CSIDL_COMMON_VIDEO 55 All Users\My Video 
CSIDL_RESOURCES 56 Resource Direcotry 
CSIDL_RESOURCES_LOCALIZED 57 Localized Resource Direcotry 
CSIDL_COMMON_OEM_LINKS 58 Links to All Users OEM specific apps 
CSIDL_CDBURN_AREA 59 USERPROFILE\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\CD Burning 
CSIDL_COMPUTERSNEARME 60 Computers Near Me (computered from Workgroup membership)
```

### .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpfull comments and answers!

this my working logon script:

```
@echo off
IF EXIST D:\USERS\%USERNAME% GOTO EXISTS
GOTO FIRSTLOGON

:FIRSTLOGON
:: Create user folder on D:\
mkdir "D:\USERS\%USERNAME%"
:: copy folder structure from template to new user folder
xcopy "D:\USERS\template\*.*" "D:\USERS\%USERNAME%" /E /Y /Q
:: Set rights on new folder
::: Remove inheritance, grant owner everything and admin everything
icacls "D:\USERS\%USERNAME%" /inheritance:r /grant %USERNAME%:(OI)(CI)F
icacls "D:\USERS\%USERNAME%" /grant Administratoren:(OI)(CI)F
:: User Notification
msg "%username%" Profilefiles were created, please logon again.
:: Logoff
ping 1.1.1.1. -n 1 -w 5000 > NUL
shutdown /l /f
GOTO END

:SECONDLOGON
:: Remove old user folders on C:\
IF EXIST "c:\Users\%username%\Desktop" rmdir /S /Q "c:\Users\%username%\Desktop"
IF EXIST "c:\Users\%username%\Documents" rmdir /S /Q "c:\Users\%username%\Documents"
IF EXIST "c:\Users\%username%\Downloads" rmdir /S /Q "c:\Users\%username%\Downloads"
IF EXIST "c:\Users\%username%\Music" rmdir /S /Q "c:\Users\%username%\Music"
IF EXIST "c:\Users\%username%\Pictures" rmdir /S /Q "c:\Users\%username%\Pictures"
GOTO END

:EXISTS
IF EXIST "c:\Users\%username%\Desktop" GOTO SECONDLOGON
echo Benutzerordner existiert bereits

:END
```

The folder redirection is done by a custom local groupolicy (it is missing on windows by default).

The import path of course are these two lines

> icacls "D:\USERS\%USERNAME%" /inheritance:r /grant %USERNAME%:(OI)(CI)F
>
> icacls "D:\USERS\%USERNAME%" /grant Administratoren:(OI)(CI)F

/inheritance:r  - this removes all inhereted rights and then i grant the current user and admin all rights which also apply to all subfolders and files (OI),(CI).